# Ibid., op. cit., with author printed

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex.

If I author and year and ibid (authoryear-ibid), the second time a same work is cited in a paragraph, the author and year are replaced by the Latin abbreviation. However, I prefer to keep the author before the Latin expression. So, instead of: Keynes (1936)... (ibid.), I want to have: Keynes (1936)... Keynes (ibid.)

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, though, does it, given what the Latin means? Why not just avoid the Latin abbreviations altogether?

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibid.): 'Ibid. (Latin, short for ibidem, meaning "in the same place")', i.e. as @cfr says having '<Author> (ibid.)' makes no sense. In order to have the author always printed, simply use `authoryear` and you'll get '<Author> (<year>)' - which is no longer than '<Author> (ibid.)' anyway, so why have the ibid.?

Comment: What cite command are you using? If I use `\textcite{foo}` to give me "Foo (2000)", I get "Foo (Ibid.)" in a subsequent `\textcite{foo}`.With `authoryear-ibid` the other commands `\cite` and `\parencite` give "Foo 2000" and "(Foo 2000)" respectively and "Ibid." and "(Ibid.)" in subsequent ibidem citations. Or have you by any chance modififed `\parencite` or `\cite`? A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would greatly help us to fully understand your issue.

Comment: I'm using \autocite

Comment: @moewe That is not what the OP wants. That is what makes sense but the OP wants something different.

Comment: @cfr Are you sure? Because I read he wants "Keynes (1936)" and then "Keynes (Ibid.)", which is exactly what I get with `authoryear-ibid` and `\textcite` (not with other `\cite` commands though).... Anyway, until the OP responds that is juts guessing.

Comment: Please provide us with an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). At this point it is really not all that easy to guess what exactly you want. In a recent version of `biblatex` with an unmodified `authoryear-ibid` `\autocite` does not yield "Keynes (1936)", but "(Keynes 1936)". `\textcite` seems to do what you want, though; you can add `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcites}` and maybe even `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{plain}{\textcite}{\textcites}` to your preamble to keep using `\autocite`.

Comment: @moewe No, I'm not sure. Now I reread what you wrote and the question, I think you maybe correct about what is wanted here.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard behaviour for `\textcite` in `authoryear-ibid`.

In order to use `\textcite` as `\autocite` stand-in, you can go with

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcites}
```

Obviously, that works with the multicite `\textcites` and `\autocites` as well.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcites}

\begin{document}
\textcite{wilde}, \textcite{wilde}

\citereset\autocite{wilde}, \autocite{wilde}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]